# Using a JS library in Chrome extension with executescript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use the notie.js alert library in my Chrome extension.

The Chrome extension monitors a specific page that has specific numbers updated at random. When a specific column of numbers changes, using a mutation observer, I am sending alerts to the screen. This works fine with the default notifications, however, they are not very customizable unfortunately. That is where I hope to use notie.

I have notie.js and notie.scss in the main directory with my other files.

Currently I'm getting **`Error in event handler: ReferenceError: notie is not defined`**

Is there an easier way to load in these two files and use the notifications?

Relevant manifest info

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*specific site url I'm watching for changes on here*"],
      "js": ["popup.js"]
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "tabs"
  ],
```

popup.js - where the message is sent

```
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('insert-lib');
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, {tab}) => {
  if (message === 'insert-lib') {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.index, {
          file: 'notie.js',
          file: 'notie.scss',
      });
      notie.alert({ type: 'success', text: 'Success!', time: 5 });
  }
});
```

Comment: Objects can't have two identical keys, the last one overrides any previous keys. Simply use two executeScript calls sequentially. And then `notie` will be available in the content script context, not in the background script. Read about architecture [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). Also, you seem to be using popup.js both in browser_action popup.html and as a content script which is wrong as these are totally different contexts.

Comment: @wOxxOm do you have an email I could contact you on, buddy?

Comment: @wOxxOm just if you wanted to help someone privately with mutation observers, chrome ext + content scripts, I saw your many helpful posts